# Set x and y co ordinates in Draw image dynamically

Tags: c#, windows, resize, drawimage

I am resizing a image using DrawImage.

```
Graphics.DrawImage(SourceImage,0,0,200,200);
```

Here the source image starts with co ordinates 0.
Suppose i need to calculate the x and y coordinates dynamically how to do i go about it?
By default, the image should start with location 20(ie; x) and 20(ie y).
If i resize the form,it should proportionally calculate according to the resized imaged,that means,if for default it is 20 than for form resize how much?

Thanks

Comment: can you clarify your question?

Comment: I need to resize the image such that the image starts with specifed location.

Comment: You mean that while resizing the starting point of image changes?

Answer (score 0):

You can register to ResizeEnd event of the form and can redraw the image. Something like;

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.ResizeEnd += new EventHandler(Form1_ResizeEnd);

    }

    void Form1_ResizeEnd(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //draw the image again using the related calculation
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

From your question it is not clear how the size of the form relates to the desired coordinates.

A form has a `ClientRectangle` property that you can use to calculate the coordinates with. If you want to display the image in the bottom-right corner for example, you would:

```
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
{
    int x = this.ClientRectangle.Width - 200;
    int y = this.ClientRectangle.Height - 200;
    e.Graphics.DrawImage(SourceImage, x, y, 200, 200);
}
```

I assume the `DrawImage` code is in a `Paint` event handler, you could then either

- use `SetStyle(ControlStyles.ResizeRedraw, true);` in the form constructor, so `Paint` is called when the form is resized
- add an event handler for the `Resize` event and call `Invalidate();` yourself